# how to remove data and then add it again jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want to achieve is when i click my "Add to My Stay" button it will load the name and price of the data. then it will automatically convert to "Remove" button after clicking "Add to my stay" If i click the Remove button it will remove the data thats been loaded. Then if i click "Add to my Stay" again it will load the data again. Can you please give me an idea on how to do this
Here is the code of my AddOns JS with its remove button js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
        name = $(this).data('name');
        price = $(this).data('price');

        console.log(id);

        $this.addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.removebtn[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
        if(id != '')

            {

                    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "Pages/addonajax",
                    data:{id:id,
                        name:name,
                        price:price},


                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            console.dir(data);
                            if (data) {

                            var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test4").append(item);


                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
});
```

My removebtn js

```
$('.removebtn').on("click", function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
        $this.addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.addons[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
    });
```

My html button with its remove

```
<button data-name = "Airport Transfer" data-price = "4300"  class="addons addon-btn trans_200" data-addon-id ="1">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
      <button class="removebtn remove-btn  is-hidden trans_200" data-addon-id ="1" >REMOVE</button>
```

is-hidden is a class based on my css that have display:none;
Here is the div id that displays the data after clicking add to my stay btn

```
 <div id = "test4"><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `element.classList.toggle` with your `is-hidden` class to switch between your add & remove button.

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
var removeBtn = document.getElementById("remove");
var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");

addBtn.onclick = () => {
  // load data
  contentDiv.innerHTML = "YOUR_DATA";
  addBtn.classList.toggle("d-none");
  removeBtn.classList.toggle("d-none");
};

removeBtn.onclick = () => {
  contentDiv.innerHTML = "";
  addBtn.classList.toggle("d-none");
  removeBtn.classList.toggle("d-none");
};
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove" class="d-none">Remove</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: for example i have 2 buttons each has their data and i clicked them both for example i clicked the remove button on button2 after clicking add to my stay. will it also remove the data on my button1?

Comment: @JedJamir The data is removed by the line `contentDiv.innerHTML = "";`. You should understand how my little piece of code is working to be able to reproduce it in your environnment. Then, if you want another button to remove your data you will use the same code as the first one to do so.

Comment: @Don'tPanic As you should know, jQuery is just a tool from Javascript, and as pure Javascript is more efficient, it is always a better choice. You can replace all the elements coming from `document.getElementById("...")` by `$("#...")[0]`.

Comment: @robinvrd can i request you to please give me an example through jquery code?

Comment: @robinvrd you missed the point. If you want to convince OP to switch, go ahead. Meanwhile, they are using jQuery - if you want your answer to be helpful, it should too.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Then, I posted a jQuery answer to the problem. But there is no way I can convince him to move to pure Javascript with a jQuery solution, that is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you could use `$("...").toggleClass("is-hidden")` to switch between your add & remove button.

You can use `.empty()` to clear your data and `.html("your_data")` to set it.

```js
var addBtn = $("#add");
var removeBtn = $("#remove");
var contentDiv = $("#content");

addBtn.click(() => {
  // load data
  contentDiv.html("YOUR_DATA");
  addBtn.toggleClass("d-none");
  removeBtn.toggleClass("d-none");
});

removeBtn.click(() => {
  contentDiv.empty();
  addBtn.toggleClass("d-none");
  removeBtn.toggleClass("d-none");
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove" class="d-none">Remove</button>
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can i display the output like this " $("#test4").append(item);" in contentDiv.html("")?

Comment: @JedJamir My `contentDiv.html("")` is the way I used in the example to append data to the div but you can use `$("#test4").append(item);` instead.